# Create Channel fails with failure to generate anchor peer update transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to create a network with 4 organizations and join each organization to a channel. However, I am running into a problem with createChannel, specifically when trying to generate an anchor peer update transaction for the additional 2 organizations I added.

[image]

This is the error I am getting. It says that org with name Org3MSP does not exist in config.

Below is my configtx.yaml, where Org3MSP is defined. Is there something else I need to add to update the config file?

```
Organizations:

# SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
# in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
- &OrdererOrg
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: OrdererOrg

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: OrdererMSP

    # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
    MSPDir: ../organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
    #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    OrdererEndpoints:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

- &Org1
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Org1MSP

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Org1MSP

    MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
    #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"

    # leave this flag set to true.
    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
          Port: 7051

- &Org2
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Org2MSP

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Org2MSP

    MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
    #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.peer', 'Org2MSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin', 'Org2MSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org2MSP.peer')"

    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
          Port: 9051

- &Org3
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Org3MSP

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Org3MSP

    MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
    #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.peer', 'Org3MSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.peer')"

    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        - Host: peer0.org3.example.com
          Port: 11051

- &Org4
    # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
    # of the fabric.git development environment
    Name: Org4MSP

    # ID to load the MSP definition as
    ID: Org4MSP

    MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org4.example.com/msp

    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
    #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.admin', 'Org4MSP.peer', 'Org4MSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.admin', 'Org4MSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.admin')"
        Endorsement:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org4MSP.peer')"

    AnchorPeers:
        # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
        # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
        # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
        - Host: peer0.org4.example.com
          Port: 13051
```

The profiles in configtx.yaml for FourOrgsChannel is below:

```
Profiles:

FourOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg
        Capabilities:
            <<: *OrdererCapabilities
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org4
                - *Org4

FourOrgsChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
            - *Org4
            - *Org4
        Capabilities:
            <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

The command i am running is `./network.sh up createChannel` and the output of that is below:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think... just typo

```yaml
    Consortiums:
        SampleConsortium:
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org4 -> Org3
                - *Org4

FourOrgsChannel:
    Consortium: SampleConsortium
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Application:
        <<: *ApplicationDefaults
        Organizations:
            - *Org1
            - *Org2
            - *Org4 -> Org3
            - *Org4
```